PSTricks' regression issue: The graph is missing now
Several years ago the following code produced a correct graph with latex-dvips-ps2pdf but now the graph is missing when I compile with either lualatex or latex-dvips-ps2pdf.  What is wrong?

\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,filecontents,siunitx}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.data}
60      0
70      2
80      8
90      24
100     56
110     86 
120     110
130     120
\end{filecontents*}

\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
    Dy=10,
    Dx=10,
        Ox=60,
        tickwidth=1.2pt,
    subticksize=1,
    xsubticks=5,
    ysubticks=5,
    subtickcolor=gray,
        subtickwidth=.8pt,
    xAxisLabel=\huge Mass (\si{\gram}),
    xAxisLabelPos={c,-7},
    yAxisLabel=\huge Cumulative Frequency,
    yAxisLabelPos={-6,c},
    llx=-2,
    lly=-2,
    urx=1,
    ury=1,  
}
\readdata{\mydata}{test.data}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[style=mygrid,xticksize=0 120,yticksize=0 70](60,0)(130,120){12.5cm}{20cm}
\listplot[plotstyle=cspline,linecolor=black,linewidth=2.4pt,showpoints]{\mydata}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}


It works for me. Maybe make sure you don't have a previous empty file test.data, or use \begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{test.data}.

I see. overwrite is mandatory. Problem solved.

This work (TL2024 update+lualatex):
\DocumentMetadata{}
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,siunitx}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\begin{filecontents*}{test.data}
60      0
70      2
80      8
90      24
100     56
110     86 
120     110
130     120
\end{filecontents*}

\newpsstyle{mygrid}
{
    Dy=10,
    Dx=10,
        Ox=60,
        tickwidth=1.2pt,
    subticksize=1,
    xsubticks=5,
    ysubticks=5,
    subtickcolor=gray,
        subtickwidth=.8pt,
    xAxisLabel=\huge Mass (\si{\gram}),
    xAxisLabelPos={c,-7},
    yAxisLabel=\huge Cumulative Frequency,
    yAxisLabelPos={-6,c},
    llx=-2,
    lly=-2,
    urx=1,
    ury=1,  
}
\readdata{\mydata}{test.data}
\begin{document}
\begin{psgraph}[style=mygrid,xticksize=0 120,yticksize=0 70](60,0)(130,120){12.5cm}{20cm}
\listplot[plotstyle=cspline,linecolor=black,linewidth=2.4pt,showpoints]{\mydata}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}


